# "Statement modifier" iteration over a hash?

Tags: perl, loops, foreach, syntax, iterator

I find myself wanting to use statement-modifier forms of iteration over hashes in Perl (v5):

```
my %h = (...);
do_something($_[0], $_[1]) for each %h;  ### $_[0] => key, $_[1] => val
```

Or:

```
my %h = (...);
my @ary = %h;
do_something($_[0], $_[1]) for splice(@ary, 0, 2);
```

Of course neither of these forms exist. Just curious if there has been any work to support the use of `splice` or `each` with the statement-modifier form of `for`?  In either Perl 6 or, via backport, v5?

Comment: `each` isn't even a loop.

Comment: @melpomene Good point, I've updated the post to put `each` on the same footing as `splice`

Comment: `for each %h` already does something else: `each` returns a two-element list (key, value) and `for` iterates over it.

Comment: By "statement modifier", do you mean a `do_something(...)` function that modifies the values of `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`?

Comment: @mob: By "statement modifier" I mean the Perl syntax described here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some great functions in [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) and [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) to help with situations like this. In particular, take a look at `pairs`:

```
use List::Util qw{pairs};

do_something($_->[0], $_->[1]) foreach pairs %h;
```

Or if you can stomach a map in void context:

```
use List::Util qw{pairmap};

pairmap { do_something($a, $b) } %h;
```

Comment: Ah, List::Util, I should've known :) I also came up with the following that works too: `do_something($_->[0], $_->[1]) for map { CORE::state @bob; push @bob, $_; @bob % 2 ? () : do {my @tmp = @bob; @bob = (); \@tmp} } %h` (Maybe List::Utils::pairs does something similar behind the scenes?) I just want to see what others come up with so I'll leave it open another day. Otherwise your answer seems acceptable.

Comment: @textral, `do {my @tmp = @bob; @bob = (); \@tmp}` is a long way of writing `[splice(@bob)]`. And your solution fails hard (i.e. poorly) if an odd number of arguments is provided.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution is the following:

```
do_something($_, $h{$_}) for keys %h;
```

If you want to save memory, you could use `each` as usual.

```
{ my ($k, $v);  do_something($k, $v) while ($k, $v) = each(%h); }
```

Of course, it's much cleaner without using a statement modifier.

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each(%h)) { do_something($k, $v); }
```

Finally, if you aren't actually dealing with a hash, could use `pairs` from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util).

```
use List::Util qw( pairs );

do_something(@$_) for pairs %h;
```

This last approach is very wasteful as it inefficiently creates a multitude of arrays.

Comment: Oh that's right: I've used your first form before... don't know why I didn't think of it this time. And even though it's probably the best way, I think I have to accept @mwp's answer because my original question (even though I worded it poorly) was more about how to consume more than one element at a time off a list using looping statement modifiers. I understand that technically Perl doesn't (currently?) allow that, but at least `List::Util::pairs` gives the "impression" of exactly that (and @mwp posted about `List::Util::pairs` first).

Comment: Note that you can still use `each` like you always do

Comment: And I'm not sure why you say that using `pairs` is mwp's solution; I also proposed it, and I even provided a simpler way of using it.

Comment: @mwp posted `pairs` as an answer 8 hours before you did.  But yes your `@$_` expansion of the arrayref returned by `pairs` is easier on the eye than mwp's usage

Comment: Re "*posted pairs as an answer 8 hours before you did.*", I was aware of that. I simply pointed out that twice you posted you were accepting mwp's answer because they used `pairs`, which makes no sense.

Comment: a minor improvement to your `while` solution: `do_something(@_) while @_ = each %h`

Comment: That's very dangerous and should be avoided

Comment: Ok, while setting elements of `@_` is dangerous, setting `@_` as a whole like that is not. Still, messing with global variables --especially one so special-- is not the way to go.

Comment: is this safer? `do_something(@_) while local @_ = each %h`

Comment: The `local` doesn't do anything there because there are no curlies to limit it

Comment: sorry to dig up an old post, but I have since tested `do_something(@_) while local @_ = each %h` and it works: anything assigned to `@_` before the command was run remains preserved in `@_` after the command has run

Comment: @textral, Ok, but it still unreadable (unintuitive, unexpected behaviour), and it still uses `each` which doesn't handle problems well.

Answer (score 0):

You may shorten

```
{my ($k, $v);  do_something($k, $v) while ($k, $v) = each(%h); }
```

to

```
do_something($a, $b) while ($a, $b) = each %h;
```

as $a and $b are already declared for sort.